# How to execute a command with multi-byte characters using system function in C++

Tags: c++, batch-file

I am trying to do something like below:

```
string command = "executable.exe .\\テストプログラム\\filename.ext";
int retval = system(command.c_str());
```

Upon debugging, I have discovered that the multi-byte characters are not recognized and were represented in random characters.

I have also tried storing the command in a batch file first and then executing the batch file.

```
filesystem::path batFile = filesystem::path(".\batFile.bat");
string command = "executable.exe .\\テストプログラム\\filename.ext";
writeBatCmd(batFile, command);
int retval = system(batFile.string().c_str());
```

My findings were that the multi-byte characters were stored correctly in the .bat file but on execution, the same as above still occurs.

Executing the created .bat file in cmd runs the command correctly.

Using CreateProcess function instead of system function does not change the behavior.

My initial guess was that the need to convert the string to c_str was what caused the behavior but writing the command in a .bat file and then executing the .bat disproved it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:

Tried solutions:
**Solution 1**
Setting locale to utf8 then calling the program directly. The command to execute the program is stored in a wstring object. When the multi-byte characters are hardcoded in the wstring object, there is no problem.
Example:

```
wstring cmd = L"executable.exe .\\テストプログラム\\filename.ext";
```

When something like this is executed, the characters starting from the multi-byte characters up to the end of the string are truncated:

```
wstring cmd = L"executable.exe " + pathToFile + L"\\filename.ext";
// cmd value: "executable.exe .\"
```

**Solution 2**
I have also tried using u16string object, when this is used, the command is stored correctly. The problem with this is that I cannot call system function on it since it is u16string, are there any system function that can be used for u16string? or is there a way of converting u16string to wstring without possibility of changing multi-byte characters?

```
u16string cmd = u"executable.exe .\\テストプログラム\\filename.ext";
// cmd value: executable.exe .\テストプログラム\filename.ext
```

**Solution 3**
I tried setting locale to utf8, then storing command in a .bat file and then executing the .bat file. Upon execution, the command is stored correctly in the .bat file. On call of the .bat file, the multi-byte characters are not recognized/displayed as single byte characters.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
filesystem::path batFile = filesystem::path(".\batFile.bat");
u16string cmd = u"executable.exe .\\テストプログラム\\filename.ext";
// cmd value: executable.exe .\テストプログラム\filename.ext
writeAsBat(batFile , cmd);
// batfile content: 
//executable.exe .\テストプログラム\filename.ext
//EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
int retval = system(batFile.string().c_str());
/*
Output: 
in .bat file: executable.exe .\テストプログラム\filename.ext
on execution of .bat file: executable.exe .\チE¹トゅログラム\filename.ext
*/
```

Comment: Are you sure it is caused by some fault in your launcher code, not `executable.exe`? How does it behave when you execute `executable.exe .\テストプログラム\filename.ext` from Command Prompt?

Comment: Typically OS-related functions on Windows that accept `char *` are not designed to work with multibyte character sets. You need to use alternatives accepting `wchar_t *`, For example `_wsystem` instead of `system` and wide strings.

Comment: @MikeCAT executing the .bat file in command prompt behaves correctly.

Comment: @user7860670 I'll try that

Thanks all!

Update: still the same incorrect behavior encountered

Comment: Windows is a Unicode OS (UTF16). Your code uses single-byte characters though, which means the string would be translated using the configured locale **in any OS, including Mac and Linux**. C++ supports Unicode strings and literals since C++11. At the very least, use `u16string` and `char16_t`

Comment: Many executables are still not full Unicode aware which means they don't support argument strings encoded in Unicode. If creation of short 8.3 names is __not__ disabled which is usually the case on Windows, it is the common workaround for a Unicode aware application like yours coded in C++ with Unicode support, to get the short file name with [GetShortPathNameW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) which consists always only of ASCII characters and run the executable with `CreateProcess` with short file name.

Answer (score 1):

Windows internally uses UTF-16 for all system functions.

If you call the MBCS/ANSI functions as you are doing, arguments are first converted to UTF-16 using the current codepage, then interpreted and executed.

If your current codepage is set correctly - and UTF-8 is not a valid codepage - then this should work. You probably need codepage 932.

However, you should really call the wide-character functions for all purposes on Windows.

Activating my psychic debugging powers, I will guess that your C++ file is in UTF-8.

**Updated** Since April 2018 you can now set UTF-8 as the current character set in C.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#utf-8-support

**Unpacking a little more**

What is probably happening is when you compile, your C string is being converted to a sequence of bytes, probably in UTF-8 encoding. These bytes are then being written to the batch file. But **batch files cannot be written in UTF-8**, they can be written in the current codepage (whatever that is, in your case probably Japanese codepage 932).

**Solving your problem**

It looks like you want to write a batch file because you are having difficulty calling your program, and have reached for a batch file as a solution.

If that's the case you may have better luck setting the C locale to UTF-8, and calling the program directly, or using the wide-character APIs to do so.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160#utf-8-support

Comment: C++11 introduced Unicode strings, specifically the `char16_t` character type and `u16string`. There's no longer any need for the old macros. As for compiling for UNICODE - why compile for anything else on Windows?

Comment: It turns out batch files **cannot** be written in UTF-16.

Comment: As for UTF8 - that's wrong. First, there's such a codepage but that's not what's happening here. Non-Unicode programs are considered *legacy* since 1994 and the codepage they use is controlled by the system locale, whose label in the settings is `Code page used for legacy non-Unicode programs`. The expectation for the last 26 years is that programs will be compiled for Unicode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I completely agree, if writing for windows just use unicode. If writing cross-platform code e.g. Linux will want UTF-8 so the macros are useful for that.

Comment: They aren't. The macros were used before and around 2000, only by Visual C++, only to allow programs to target both the old Windows line and the new Windows NT. For cross-platform, it's .... ouch. Linux treats strings based on the locale only, so you can't even handle multi-language text **unless** you set the locale encoding to UTF8. And C++ itself hasn't standardized UTF8 yet. Until recently `char` and `string` were used for both UTF8 and non-Unicode text. We now have `u8string` and `char8_t` BUT not streams. And there's no standard way to convert between UTF8 and other codepages

Comment: So on other OSs (including Mac unfortunately) if you write in C or C++, you can either use `char` and hope the end user doesn't mess things up, or use `u16string` and explicitly convert to UTF8 using the [deprecated but not replaced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) `codecvt_utf8` conversion. Go figure

Comment: A great quantity of running code was written before any of these standards existed. In particular, one reason Windows doesn't use UTF-8 internally is because it standardised on Unicode before UTF-8 was invented.

Comment: Hi all, I updated the question. Added the tried solutions you have given. Thank you very much!